# Incorrect integer value error on creating IntegerField Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

Created IntegerField in the class of models.py

```
how_much_new_notifications = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Get such error:

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'how_much_new_notifications' at row 1")
```

How to handle with it?

Comment: Where is the error coming from? And do show the full traceback.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye the whole traceback is kind of very huge –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing any value to call?

if not, Change the field in your models.py file

```
how_much_new_notifications = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
```

**null=True** sets NULL (versus NOT NULL) on the column in your DB.

**blank=True** determines whether the field will be required in forms.

and you can put a check whether you are passing a correct value or not.

Comment: there is no value passing, I tried what you recommended, the same error still occurring

Comment: did you migrate, after changing models file?

Comment: Yes, I did migrate

Comment: the error doesn't occur after make migrations but after migrate

Comment: after changing models file. you have to makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: exactly what I did, the same mistake

Comment: can you show us your code?
Add a condition to code that if you are not passing any value then pass default zero. It may resolve your problem.

Comment: the actual problem was some mess with migrations